# Curl command on mac throwing error while making a Rest API call

Tags: api, curl, restful-authentication

I am trying to call the Uber API to get services they offer in a particular city, using the following command:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Token <MyToken>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en_EN" \
'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/products?latitude=37.7752315&longitude=-122.418075'
```

But the command is throwing the following error:

> curl: no URL specified! curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for
>   more information

Comment: What is response  and code http for that request?

Comment: Are you sure? I ran your command and got: `{"message":"No authentication provided.","code":"unauthorized"}`.  Is there some characters in your authorisation token that you didn't post here that could be messing up the command?

Comment: @Krock,
strange, but I got it worked out with Postman. Thanks